# Remove message body text from cell by keeping only email

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-docs

I would like to know what spreadsheet formula can I use, so from this email body text below

```
account@my-domain
If you would like to unsubscribe and stop receiving these emails click
here: http://email.my-domain.com/wf/unsubscribe?upn=vnghw67tgfsdhfvbqwr78gchhgf37tgnwicunffiehnwcjgbwjknhcuhecwhknvhwcvcaq7wefgasbhdfcjkbarahc.
```

I can have only the email address on new cell

What I would ideally like is this

```
Column A           Column B
see above          account@my-domain
```

I tried to add this formula on B2

```
TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"If you would like to unsubscribe and stop receiving these emails click here: http://email.my-domain.com/wf/unsubscribe?upn=*",""))
```

but it does not work. I need it work on Google Sheets. Strangely it works on MS Excel but not on Google Sheets

I hope my description is clear and someone can help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your email address is always on the first line:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND(CHAR(10),A1))
```

In other words, find the line break and grab all the text to the left of it.

Comment: Thank you, this was pretty much what I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this:
considering there is a space between domain and if and the text is in cell a3 I have used the following formula in excel:

Having your email id on the beginning of the cell you can go with this formula:

```
=MID(A3,FIND("",A3),FIND("",A3)+FIND(" ",A3)-1)
```

It may look long but it will help you to understand the idea

Comment: Thank you, although the formula was a bit more complex than above, it worked. But I only had to change the last digit from -1 to -4, because the chars "If " were being left in result cell

Answer (score -1):

If "http:" occurs in every case you can find the position of that text and use it as the starting point for the function "mid".  The length parameter of "mid" can exceed the length of the string, so you could use a literal of high value for that.

THIS:
=mid(a2,find("http",a2),100)

### will bring the full address if it is not greater than 100 characters (shouldn't be).

THIS:
=mid(a2,find("http",a2)+7,100)

### will bring the email address string without "http://" by skipping those seven characters.